# Hacer un count de un count SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta

```
Select count(device) FROM entrada
where badge = badge
group by badge
order by count desc;
```

y me arroja un listado de las veces que cada badge tiene un device, lo que quiero ahora es juntar por ejemplo si el badge uno tiene 5 y el badge 2 tiene 5 tambien me de un resultado asi

```
Cantidad Contados

    5        2
```

Un ejemplo mas explicado seria el query me regresa lo siguiente

```
'8'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'7'
'6'
'6'
'6'
'6'
'6'
'6'
```

Entonces seria agruparlos

```
Cantidad Contados
    8       1
    7       8
    6       6
```

Quiero que agrupe los resultados contandolos, no logro hacer este query

Comment: qué resultado querrías si el badge uno tiene 4 y el badge 2 tiene 6?

Comment: deja lo agrego a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lo que necesitas es usar tu consulta actual como una tabla derivada:

```
SELECT  Cantidad, 
        COUNT(*) Contados
FROM (  SELECT badge, COUNT(device) Cantidad
        FROM entrada
        GROUP BY badge) as T
GROUP BY Cantidad
;
```

O una CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT badge, COUNT(device) Cantidad
    FROM entrada
    GROUP BY badge
)
SELECT  Cantidad, 
        COUNT(*) Contados
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Cantidad
;
```

Comment: Gracias si funciona es que no me salia lo de hacer la tabla derivada pero ya si funciona lo marco como respuesta en cuanto me deje el stack

Comment: Solo una pregunta cuando usas el COUNT(*) Contados es como usar el as Contados?

Comment: @R.Nuñez en efecto es exactamente eso